# How to keep domain consistency (with or without www)?

Tags: uri, redirection

Some search engines make a difference if the site is found in example.com or www.example.com. So it's important to redirect all users from example.com/some-page to www.example.com/some-page, or the other way around.

Is it possible in Drupal 7?

Comment: it might be done via `.htaccess`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. The .htaccess file contains the following comments.

```
# If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
# can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
# URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Uncommenting one of those rewriting rules is all you need to do.

Comment: Just make sure that you check when you update Drupal core to ensure that the .htaccess file doesn't get overwritten.